# displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar does not display search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There is plenty of sample code out there, and I thought I was following it line for line; my code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // init search bar
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;

    // set up searchDisplayController
    UISearchDisplayController *searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                    initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.delegate = self;
    searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    // display search bar in nav bar
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
}
```

With that code, shouldn't I see the search bar displayed in the navigation bar? All I see in the nav bar is the cancel button. I have declared the protocols `<UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>` in my header file. What am I missing, or what could be going wrong? Thanks

Note:
Using `self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar`, the search bar displays as expected. I wonder what are the advantages of the newer `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` method..

-- Edit by tassilo --

It looks like the search bar is added to the navigation bar, but then disappears.

[image]

[image: The search bar is only displayed for a few millisecond]

Answer (score 1):

The displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar property makes it so the search bar slides into the navigation bar when the user taps it, like what happens in the Apple Mail app. You still need to add the search bar to the view somewhere.

Best way to do this is to set the tableHeaderView of a UITableViewController to the search bar.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. This worked for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem.

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

`self.searchDisplayController` is not the same as `searchDisplayController`, that you created.

So just replace `self.searchDisplayController` with `searchDisplayController`. Also, be sure that you don't have `@synchronize searchDisplayController;`